# How to remove blank space between two UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have two `UITableView`. I have set first `UITableView` `height = 600` and second `UITableView` `height = 400`. Second UITableView is below first  `UITableView`. Both `UITableView` data comes from the database. The problem is, if data in the first `UITableView` is less than its height, then it shows blank space between first and second `UITableView`. I want both `UITableView` to have height according to its data and also want to remove that blank space.

[image: This is how my UITableView looks]

Comment: Why not use one tableview?

Comment: because both table view contains different data.

Comment: Why not use one table view with two sections?

Comment: But i want two separate tableview.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't set the constraints up correctly and the UITableView is only doing what you asked it to do - set the height at 600.

To achieve the results you are looking for, you need to click the top UITableView and then click the size inspector button on the top right hand side (the little ruler) and change the "Height Equals" property constant.

If you change the constant to `< 600` then it will be **no greater than 600**. If you change it to `> 600` then it will only ever be **no less than 600**.

Comment: After doing this, still second tableview doesn't go upward . Still it shows blank space between two tableview.

Comment: Are both of your table views nested in a stack view?

Comment: No, my table view is not nested in stack view.

Comment: Well there's your problem, it needs to be in a stack view otherwise it'll just create a white space

Comment: Okay. Now I nested my both tableview in stackview but still blank space occurs. I gave spacing between two table as 20. But still it creates blank space.

Comment: Have you assigned them to fill the stack view?